# Calling getters inside a setter function vs direct access to data members

Tags: c++, class, getter-setter

The question is simple: Is it unnecessary to call getters inside setters to have access to an object's member variables? Suppose that all the getters are `inline`d and return `const` references to members.

As an example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    inline const std::uint32_t& getValue( ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    inline const std::uint32_t& getBar( ) const noexcept
    {
        return m_bar;
    }

    void setValue( const std::uint32_t value )
    {
        m_value = value * getBar() * 3; // vs m_value = value * m_bar * 3;
    }

private:
    std::uint32_t m_value;
    std::uint32_t m_bar;
};
```

Which one is more idiomatic? I think there should be no difference in the generated code by the compiler. But in terms of readability, they're a bit different. What could be the benefits of using getters instead of directly typing e.g. `m_bar`?

Comment: Makes not much sense without `virtual` getter functions? Just use your class members directly?

Comment: If your getters do some sort of validation to maintain class invariants, I can see it making sense to use those to avoid repeating the logic in other parts of the class. But when they're as simple as this example it's hard to see much point to it.

Comment: Side note: a method defined inside the class definition is automatically `inline` or something so close to it that you're unlikely to ever notice the difference

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I am aware of that. However this example is not exactly what my code looks like. It's just an MRE. I have defined the member functions of my class outside of the class declaration and thus I have had to use the `inline` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in the class always has full acess to the internal data members (and member functions too). So it is not necessary. My thoughts on if you should do it

- if the getters and particularly setters have side effects (imagine you keep a count of how many times a particular value is changed, or validate a value) then you should call them
- the overhead when compiled for release will disappear since the compiler can see that you are just reading or writing the value (if they are simple read and write get/set)
- you might get into the habit of always calling them just in case you later want them to have side effects

note I dont say whats 'best', just things to take into account

Comment: Yes, the setters contain code for validating the argument passed to each of them. But the getters are simple. They are there just for having `const` access to members. So what I understand from your words is that I should not call getters inside setters in order to improve readability since they don't have much benefit.

Comment: @digito_evo ultimately in the case you describe its a personal style choice, I cannot advise

Comment: Side note: Even if the getter has no value-add and never will, it makes a great place to hang a breakpoint so you can trap a miscreant more easily than peppering the codebase with breakpoints on direct use of the member (and, of course, missing the breakpoint on the one that actually mattered).